# Java Callables not getting synchronized

Tags: java, java-7

I thought Synchronize methods in Java are one execution at a time.
But, I see that if 2 callables are passing through the synchronize block they are getting executed in parallel.

Here is my Executor class with fixed Threadpool.

```
public class ThreadExecutor 
{

    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    public void callCallable2()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside executor callable 2 method");
        ThreadTestCallable2 t = new ThreadTestCallable2();
        executors.submit(t);
        System.out.println("Exiting executor callable 2 method");
    }

    public void callCallable1()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside the executor callable 1 method");
        ThreadTestCallable1 t = new ThreadTestCallable1();
        executors.submit(t);
        System.out.println("exiting the executor callable 1 method");
    }

}
```

My callable classes are:

```
public class ThreadTestCallable1 implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside the threadtestcallable 1");
        ThreadHelperTest t = new ThreadHelperTest();
        t.test();
        System.out.println("Exiting the threadtestcallable 1");
        return null;
    }

}

public class ThreadTestCallable2 implements Callable{

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside the threadtestcallable 2");
        ThreadHelperTest t = new ThreadHelperTest();
        t.test();
        System.out.println("exitting the threadtestcallable 2");
        return null;
    }


}
```

My callable synchronize method is in the helper class.

```
public class ThreadHelperTest 
{
    public void test()
    {
        test1();
    }

    public synchronized void test1()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping for 10 sec's T-name: "+ 
            Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            System.out.println("wokeup T-Name: "+ 
            Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        ThreadExecutor t = new ThreadExecutor();
        t.callCallable1();
        t.callCallable2();
    }

}
```

the final output for the above execution is I see both callables enter into the synchronize method at a time, which should not happen, Anything wrong with the Monitor Object .?

Please find the result of the above code:

```
Inside the executor callable 1 method
exiting the executor callable 1 method
Inside executor callable 2 method
Inside the threadtestcallable 1
Exiting executor callable 2 method
Inside the threadtestcallable 2
Sleeping for 10 sec's T-name: pool-1-thread-1
Sleeping for 10 sec's T-name: pool-1-thread-2
wokeup T-Name: pool-1-thread-1
Exiting the threadtestcallable 1
wokeup T-Name: pool-1-thread-2
exitting the threadtestcallable 2
```

Please suggest me if anything needs to be changed.
to get these methods synchronized.

Comment: i suspect the issue here is creating new objects , thus creating two different monitors for two objects.

if thats the case please suggest any alternative plans to achieve synchronization between the callables.

Comment: `ThreadTestCallable1` and `ThreadTestCallable2` have to have a field `ThreadHelperTest t`. You then create the callables and pass in the same instance of `ThreadHelperTest`.

Comment: The issue here is **definitely** that you have multiple ThreadHelperTest instances.  The rule is that a non-static `synchronized` provides exclusion against other  `synchronized` calls *on the same instance*.  You have different instances.  Therefore no mutual exclusion, and no synchronization / happens before relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your callables have their own instance of `ThreadHelperTest`. Calls to [synchronized method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) of different instances are allowed to interleave.

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on *the same object* to interleave.

You could pass the same instance of `ThreadHelperTest` to your callables or use whatever other shared mutex to synchronize on.

Comment: Any chances of using the Util.Concurrent.Locks..?

what needs to be done to achieve to synchronization between these two callables..?

any thoughts.?

I have in fact tried locking mechanisms too, But those are also not working, Any ideas of using the Static fields to synchronize.?

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV Everything is in the answer. You don't really need `java.util.concurrent.locks`, just synchronize on something shared.